# Column added to table but does not show up

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to Postgres.  I created a database and a table, then I added columns to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE NDQ01
ADD COLUMN Date, date
```

To verify, I did:

```
\d+ ndq01
```

and the output is:

```
Table "public.ndq01"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description

--------+------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
```

My new column name "Date" does not show up.  What did I do wrong?

Thanks very much.

---

UPDATE:

This is the error from Putty:

```
dbfinance01-# alter table ndq01 add column Date date;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "alter"

LINE 2: alter table ndq01 add column Date date;
```

Comment: Could it be that autocommit is off and you did't commit the changes?

Comment: I don't know about autocommit, but I just added the Date column again and followed it by COMMIT.  But it still doesn't show up.  I though commit was only for  adding records to a column, not for adding a column to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `alter table` did not succeed. Try removing the comma:

```sql
alter table NDQ01 add column Date date;
```

Check out `\h alter table` in psql for more information.

To clarify based on other answers, according to the current docs, `date` is not a reserved word in Postgres, and can be set as a column name (tested on version 11.2):

```
=# \d+ ndq01;
                                 Table "public.ndq01"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
 date   | date |           |          |         | plain   |              |
```

[SQL Key Words docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: I'm in psql, it doesn't like the semicolon.  When I remove it, the command executes but the column still doesn't show up.

Comment: I posted it in my question because it's multiline.  See above.

Comment: The `-#` means you are already in the middle of a statement; Postgres is waiting for you to finish. `^C` until it reads `=#` and try the alter statement again.

Comment: Now it returns ALTER TABLE so that's better than before.  Do I have to commit?  I don't think so, but just wanted to ask.

Comment: Unless you're in a transaction, it should already be committed.

Comment: Brilliant - now that column shows up when I do d+.  Thanks very much.